# Why class base on QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature not work in qgis python plugin?

Tags: qgis, python

I try to create plugin to hide layer on selection by click on map. I do this code :

```
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        tr = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature.__init__(self, canvas, None)
        self.layers=[]
            
    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button()== Qt.LeftButton and not self.layers:
            names = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
            found_features = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), names, QgsMapToolIdentify.TopDownAll)
            root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
            for f in found_features:
                layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(f.mLayer.name())[0]
                if f.mLayer.name() not in self.layers and QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).isVisible() == True:
                    self.layers.append(f.mLayer.name())
            qgis.utils.iface.statusBarIface().showMessage(self.tr("Hide {}".format(self.layers[0])))
            return None
        if event.button()== Qt.LeftButton and self.layers:    
            layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(self.layers[0])[0]
            QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
            self.layers.pop(0)
            if not self.layers:
                self.deactivate()
                qgis.utils.iface.statusBarIface().showMessage("")
            else :
                qgis.utils.iface.statusBarIface().showMessage(self.tr("Hide {}".format(self.layers[0])))
            return None
        if event.button()== Qt.RightButton and self.layers:    
            self.layers.pop(0)
            if not self.layers:
                self.deactivate()
                qgis.utils.iface.statusBarIface().showMessage("")
            else :
                qgis.utils.iface.statusBarIface().showMessage(self.tr("Hide {}".format(self.layers[0])))        
            return None
            
    def activate(self):
        # Deal with changing the button text + change cursor
        qgis.utils.iface.statusBarIface().showMessage(self.tr("Select layers to hide"))

t = HidingLayerbyClick(qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas())
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(t)
```

This code work on QGIS console python. But when I try to insert this code in plugin, the clicks in canvas not are not detect.

Anyone have idea ?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing your plugin structure, but some general advice: make sure the instance of your map tool class is declared as an instance attribute of your plugin class. Also, in your plugin you should have a reference to iface e.g `self.iface`. So, in your plugin, do: `self.map_tool = HidingLayerByClick(self.iface.mapCanvas())` `self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.map_tool)`.

Comment: You are right, my map tools was not intance.  All is ok now. thanks you !

Comment: great! No problem :-)